# Carthrob's Shipping Rules

Tags: cartthrob

I am having some difficulty understanding why I can't get some shipping rules to work.

I am using the 'By Location - Price Threshold' shipping set in Cartthrob.

I have checked and the country code is being saved in the correct field etc, so I am guessing its something to with how I have set out my shipping rules. I have looked on the CT website, but the documentary doesnt particular explain how the correct layout should be.

I have attached the image below. Is say 10-20 the correct way to enter thresholds?

[image]

**UPDATE**

The shipping rules I need are for Great Britain, and the rest of the world. GLOBAL covers everything as far as I know in CT. I then want to have different shipping costs dependant on the price. So if the price is between 0-10 and the users shipping country code is GBR £1.20. if between 10-25 £2.50 etc

Comment: Can you explain your shipping rules in more detail so we can get a sense of the screenshot setup. Thanks

Comment: I have just added an update for you Siebird. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You'll see in the column description above that a threshold of 0-10 is entered as simply "10". Basically the way they have it set up is that thresholds are articulated by the maximum value applicable, and i believe the threshold logic loops through the items you have setup looking for the one that applies. So if you set up thresholds of 10, 20 and 30, it automatically treats them as 0-10.00, 10.01-20.00, and 20.01-30.00 respectively.  What it does mean, of course, is that they can't overlap, because then the logic check would return more than one applicable rule, and I don't know how it would react to that.

Comment: Also, the `GLOBAL` values in the price threshold column should be a number that is higher than any product or possible cart total. So in this case you should just use a arbitrary number like `99999` that will never be met